# Admob Best practice for a Viewpager

Tags: android, caching, android-viewpager, admob

I am using a viewpager with fragments, the number of fragments is usually around 4 to 5. ATM I have an adview inside each of the fragment. But that would mean calling up 4 to 5 adviews ( which are held in the parent Activity). Which doesn't seem to be efficient, and I am not sure if it is in accordance with AdMobs policies. 
Or is it better to place the ad below the viewpager and it will remain fixed. I am also using navigation drawers, I am a little worried if it will cause other problems.

Also is it ok to use a singleton to cache the adview across activities. As it will reduce the need to fetch a new adview each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a single ad view below the view pager would be more efficient and less distracting for the user, too.

Do not try to cache the adview (or any view for that matter) across activities. You will leak the activity context and memory.